Firewalld: adding a source IP blocks SSH. Different behaviour between versions?
I have two servers with different versions of RHEL and firewalld. Both are configured the same, but they are behaving differently when I add a source IP to a zone.
Server A:
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)
# firewall-cmd --version
0.6.3

Server B:
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 9.3 (Plow)
# firewall-cmd --version
1.2.5

Both servers have a very basic firewalld config, and I can ssh into both of them (note the inclusion of the ssh service in both configs):
A:
# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens32
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client mysql ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

B:
# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eno8303
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

The servers are going to host a MariaDB database so I need to ensure port 3306 is allowed. With no other changes, I run the following commands which (from experience) allows port 3306 traffic from the specific IP address 192.168.1.2:
# firewall-cmd --new-zone=test --permanent
success
# firewall-cmd --zone=test --add-source=192.168.1.2 --permanent
success
# firewall-cmd --zone=test --add-port=3306/tcp --permanent
success
# firewall-cmd --reload

After running these commands, I can still SSH into Server A from IP address 192.168.1.2, but I can't SSH into Server B. I can, however, SSH into Server B from other machines. From 192.168.1.2 into Server B I get:
# ssh ServerB
ssh: connect to host ServerB port 22: No route to host

If I create the zone without the --add-source option, SSH works fine, so it seems like this option has a different behaviour on the newer server. Is that correct? I cannot find any other reason for this not working.

It looks like older versions of firewalld were allowing Zone Drifting.
What is zone drifting?
A user may configure a source-based zoneFoo - a zone to which you’ve added sources via --add-source. If zoneFoo uses a --set-target of default, then the packets will be allowed to ingress a second interface-based zone. This includes the catch-all default zone.
Sources:
Firewalld blog post: https://firewalld.org/2020/01/allowzonedrifting
Alma Linux forum: https://almalinux.discourse.group/t/adding-source-ip-to-specific-zone-prevents-same-ip-from-accessing-services-in-other-zones/2539/3

This sounds right. I found a post about enabling zone drift inf to maintain backwards compatibility in newer versions, but mine doesn’t even have the entry in firewalld.conf. Manually adding it didn’t work.

Im still not sure what the solution is though. Will need to research further.

I have looked into firewalld repository, AllowZoneDrifting has been completely removed by this PR: https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/pull/736 so the only way you have is to add ssh to the new zone of Server B
